# Why browsers caches 301 redirect for http://example.com and use it for http://example.com:8080?

Tags: browser-cache, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I have two site on two different web server(**NGINX & nodejs**) on my **CentOS** server.
in my *NGINX* config, I have set ***http://example.com*** to be redirected to ***https://example.com*** permanently.
on the other side, the URL ***http://example.com:8080*** are handle by **nodejs** and is not redirected to anywhere.

**Scenario**

When I request ***http://example.com*** in my browser (**Chrome, firefox or safari**), it's redirected to ***https://example.com*** and this is OK. when I enter ***http://example.com:8080***, it's also redirected to ***https://example.com:8080*** and this is not correct.

When I clear browser cache, the URL ***http://example.com:8080*** worked correctly but after entring ***http://example.com***, the URL ***http://example.com:8080*** redirected again to **HTTPS**. Can anyone help me about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably experience what is defined by [HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) specification.

You need to check response of the `https://example.com` request. It probably contains `Strict-Transport-Security` header which instructs browser to rewrite all URIs of `example.com` **domain** requests to use secure scheme. Relevant excerpt from [8.3. URI Loading and Port Mapping section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#page-19) of HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) specification:

> The UA MUST replace the URI scheme with "https" [RFC2818], and
> if the URI contains an explicit port component of "80", then
> the UA MUST convert the port component to be "443", or
>
> if the URI contains an explicit port component that is not
> equal to "80", the port component value MUST be preserved;
> otherwise,
>
> if the URI does not contain an explicit port component, the UA
> MUST NOT add one.
>
> NOTE:  These steps ensure that the HSTS Policy applies to HTTP
> over any TCP port of an HSTS Host.
>
> NOTE:  In the case where an explicit port is provided (and to a
> lesser extent with subdomains), it is reasonably likely that
> there is actually an HTTP (i.e., non-secure) server running on
> the specified port and that an HTTPS request will thus fail
> (see item 6 in Appendix A ("Design Decision Notes")).

For more information check [Strict-Transport-Security MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security).

Comment: Wow it worked. thanks a lot @Leonid. I removed `add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000` from *NGINX* and it worked.